# How to perform combineByKey() for windowed operations in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am looking for something like `combineByKeyAndWindow()`, however this is not available. Is there a way to mimic its function using `combineByKey()` and `foreachRDD`?

EDITED:

```
object DirectKafkaWordCount {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
if (args.length < 2) {
  System.err.println(s"""
    |Usage: DirectKafkaWordCount <brokers> <topics>
    |  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers
    |  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from
    |
    """.stripMargin)
  System.exit(1)
}

val Array(brokers, topics) = args

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafkaWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

val lines = messages.map(_._2)

var counter = 0
lines.window(Seconds(10),Seconds(5)).foreachRDD { (rdd : RDD[String], time : Time) =>

    val wc = rdd.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
    wc.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file:///home/vdep/output/temp"+counter)
    counter = counter + 1
} 

ssc.checkpoint("/home/vdep/kafkaOutput/kafkachkpt/") 
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

The above is a simple wordCount program using `.window()` & `.foreachRDD()`. I am saving the results to a file on every iteration(RDD). However only temp0 is saved in the output folder.

`lines` is a Kafka DirectStream.

But the code words as expected without `.window()`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably achieve the same results by doing:

```
dstream.window(...).transform(rdd=> rdd.combineByKey(...))
```

Although you will miss the optimization that reducers offer on the size of the data in the window.

Comment: It does work, but introducing `.window()` doesn't iterate among RDDs in the DStream. I'am trying to run `dstream.window(...).foreachRDD(rdd=> rdd.combineByKey(...))`. It stops at the end of first iteration.

Comment: There's only 1 RDD in a DStream at a point in time. In the case of `window` ops, it's an union of the individual RDDs belonging to the given time interval. So, `dstream.window(....).foreach{_ => println("blink"))` will only blink once.

Comment: ... once each window interval

Comment: thanks maasg. I get it, `.window()` unions the RDD in that window length and stops. What I am looking for is, some function that doesn't stop after union but continuously proceeds for RDDs in next intreval.

Comment: @vdep could you further clarify? `window` will continuously process incoming data following the `size` and `interval` parameters. Let's say your base streaming interval is 2 seconds, a `window(size=12, interval=2)` will give you a window of 10 seconds updated every 2 seconds. `window(size=12, interval=6)` will give an updated window of size 12 seconds every 6 seconds and so on...  they all work continuously  over the dstream, so I don't understand the comment about "some function that doesn't stop"

Comment: for example `dstream.window(4,2).foreachRDD{rdd => println("blink")) } `, should print blink every 2 seconds with window length of 4. But blink is printed only once (i.e the first time window). The iteration for RDDs for next time-window in not happening (It always stops with the RDDs in first window, i checked this with an accumulator. Accumulator value is not incremented in next iteration, from which i believe there is only one RDD hence only one iteration).

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? That's not normal behavior.

Comment: @vdep could you include the stream creation, start and wait for stop?

Comment: And you don't see any exceptions being thrown? Logs? The code looks OK to me.

Comment: The runs fine, there are no warnings/exception

Comment: Got it, the problem is with `.saveAsTextFile()`. It doesn't stop whenever `.window()` is used, I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: That would be worth putting in another question. Maybe somebody can help with that.